# new ApolloClient() results in WebPack error?

Tags: reactjs, apollo

Im trying to get a basic React / Apollo app set up.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ApolloClient, ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import './App.css';
import Contacts from './Contacts';

const client = new ApolloClient();

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
          </header>
          <Contacts />
        </div>
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

But it appears this line:

```
const client = new ApolloClient();
```

Results in an error:

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_react_apollo__.ApolloClient is not a constructor
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try `import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using v2, there's a lot of changes from v1, see [apollo docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/setup.html)

You have to import from apollo-client now :

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
```

But the provider is still from react-apollo :

```
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
```